# What's the most efficient way of selecting all html tags that have a specific data-[propriety] regardless of value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add some kind of on the fly configuration for my require js modules. I declared some html tags like this:

```
    <header data-module='js/views/header'>

    </header>

    <section data-module='js/views/homepage' data-hash='/'>

    </section>

    <section data-module='js/views/statistics' data-hash='/statistics'>

    </section>

    <footer data-module='js/views/footer'>

    </footer>
```

And the jQuery query I use in order to get all elements that have data-module set to something different than null is:

```
            var $viewModules = $('[data-module]');
```

Is there a more efficient way fo selecting those elements? I never used the data selector in jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: Since you don't really have a common `tagName` or class to use to further reduce the search, that would be the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @KevinB Why not make that an answer?

Comment: @KevinB I was afraid someone would say that. This isn't really fast, but since it will be run at the beginning of the execution, and there won't be to many tags present before this is run, maybe it's ok like this.

Comment: I expected the question to be answered 6 times by the time I submitted the comment.

Comment: For the sake of random curiosity, [a jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/attribute-selector-vs-filter). I'm not sure if the small number of elements in the HTML is going to skew the results, but using the attribute-selector is definitely much, much faster than the only other way I could think of to get the same set of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hard one, however, seeing you asked about efficiency, using [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on the document seems slightly faster, by up to 10%.

```
var $viewModules = $(document).find('[data-module]');
```

See [**Test-Results**](http://jsperf.com/select-all-by-attribute)

If I had to take a guess to why it is faster I'd say somehow find is optimized behind the scenes but that is just a guess.

Comment: To me it looks like the difference is within the error margin. There won't be any noticeable differences.

Comment: I would say it's faster because `$()` exits quicker with `$(document)` than it does with `$(selector)`, then `.find()` goes directly to looking for elements rather than trying to figure out if you are creating or selecting elements.

Comment: @FelixKling: Though I do agree with you, I only posted it because OP specifically mentioned efficiency and the difference in execution time was in most runs between 3% and 10%. Sure the difference is never noticed but a difference there is nonetheless. But yes, you are absolutely right I would not go start changing my code now all of a sudden :) I also added the custom javascript method `getElementsByAttribute` by `Robert Nyman` to the test now but it is the slowest of them all.

Comment: When I ran the code a couple of times, the improvement was at **max** 3% and most of the time both methods were the same. That just shows that there is not a *reliable* improvement across browsers. Just saying :)

Comment: You are right, it runs faster by a few operations per sec in every browser I tested it, 5 out of 7 times. :) Thank you!

Comment: @FelixKling: Totally agree with different possible results across browsers. I also run it a few more times and in average `find` executes 1000 more operations per second than `$()`. According to the graphs anyways. But yeah, this is such minor differences I would be very surprised to see any difference on performance, even on a mobile app.

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't really have a common `tagName` or `className` to use to further reduce the search, your current way would be the most efficient way of doing it.

```
var $viewModules = $('[data-module]');
```